# syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For some reason I cannot use render in a one line conditional.

Example, this works:

```
@key = Key.find_by_patient_id(5).nil? ? @key : @key
```

But this does not:

```
@key = Key.find_by_patient_id(5).nil? ? render :index : render :index
```

Error message:

> syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG,
>   expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   ...y_patient_id(5).nil? ? render
>   :index : render :index

Comment: Please put newline somewhere, it is not clear what you need to get.

Comment: I have added the error message on a newline, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Please describe in words what you want to do with this code.

Comment: I'm trying to use render in a one line conditional, but it doesn't like it.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the colon is ambiguous whether it represents a symbol or the separator. Grouping each condition should fix the syntax error:

```
@key = Key.find_by_patient_id(5).nil? ? (render :index) : (render :index)
```

Comment: Btw, I would say this statement is still ambiguous to the reader… I'm pretty sure it's setting the value of `@key` to the return value of `render`, which I don't think is what you want it to do.